# Is it possible to add YAWS appmods config at runtime?

Tags: erlang, yaws

I embedded YAWS in my application at production environment, and I use the function `yaws:start_embedded/4` to start YAWS.

Below is my code:

```
Id = "my_server",
GconfList = [{logdir, "./log"}, {id, Id}],  
SconfList = [{docroot, Docroot},
  {port, Port},
  {listen, Listen},
  {appmods, [      
    {"/rest", mod_rest, []},
    {"/file", mod_file, []}      
  ]}
],
yaws:start_embedded(Docroot, SconfList, GconfList, Id).
```

I'd like to add another appmod, e.g: `{"/upload", mod_upload, []}`

Is it possible to add appmods at runtime without restarting YAWS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add appmods at runtime by first retrieving the current configuration, using it to create a new configuration containing your new appmods, and then setting the new configuration.

1. Call `yaws_api:getconf/0` to get a 3-tuple `{ok, GlobalConf, ServerConfs}` where `GlobalConf` is the global Yaws configuration and `ServerConfs` is a list of lists of Yaws server configurations. The global conf is a record type named `gconf`, and the server conf is a record type named `sconf`; both of these record types are defined in the `yaws.hrl` header file.
2. Work through the server configurations to find the one containing the appmods you want to change. This is slightly tricky because you're dealing with a list of lists, and you need to keep the shape of the overall data structure unchanged.
3. Once you find the `sconf`, create a new `sconf` instance from it by adding your new appmod to its current list of appmods. Each element of the appmod list is a tuple consisting of a URL path for the appmod and the name of the appmod module. An appmod tuple can also optionally contain a third field consisting of a list of paths under the first path to be excluded; see the description of `exclude_paths` in [the Yaws appmod documentation](http://yaws.hyber.org/appmods.yaws) for more details.
4. Replace the existing `sconf` value in `ServerConfs` with your new value.
5. Call `yaws_api:setconf/2` to set the new configuration, passing the existing `GlobalConf` as the first argument and the new `ServerConfs` containing your new `sconf` as the second argument.

The `am_extend` module below shows how to do this. It exports an `add/1` function that takes a function that can identify and augment the appmods in the particular server you care about.

```
-module(am_extend).
-export([add/1]).

add(AppmodAdder) ->
    {ok, GlobalConf, ServerConfs} = yaws_api:getconf(),
    NewServerConfs = add_appmod(ServerConfs, AppmodAdder),
    yaws_api:setconf(GlobalConf, NewServerConfs).

add_appmod(ServerConfs, AppmodAdder) ->
    lists:foldl(fun(Val, Acc) ->
                        Acc ++ [AppmodAdder(A) || A <- Val]
                end, [], ServerConfs).
```

An example of using this code is to pass the function below as the `AppmodAdder` argument for `am_extend:add/1`. For this example, we're looking for a server that has an appmod path `"/sse"` so we can add another appmod to that server for the path `"/sse2"`. Any server conf we don't care about is just returned unchanged.

```
-include_lib("yaws/include/yaws.hrl").

add_sse2(#sconf{appmods=AM}=SC) ->
    case lists:keyfind("/sse", 1, AM) of
        false ->
            SC;
        _ ->
            SC#sconf{appmods=[{"/sse2", my_sse_module}|AM]}
    end.
```

Note that our `add_sse2/1` function must be compiled with `yaws.hrl` included so it has the definition for the `sconf` record available.

Comment: I tried the code which you provide, and it works, and will not affect other connected connection, thank you very much !